# Log file locked in a web application

Tags: c#, web, logfile

My web application in c# writes in a log file the tasks performed by the users.
Everything goes well as long as the number of users is small.
However, when there are many users working with the application, the writes to the log file fail because it is in use.

Is there a way to sequence the writes to the log file so that all user activity is recorded?

I know can use a database for writing log but i want to make it simpler.

Comment: Which log library are you using? You are using a log library right? Not a self made log implementation right?

Comment: As Steve said, a log lib handles all this for you. If you're using your own implementation you can create a queue and have your logger function go through the array and shift the logs one by one as you write the file, without closing the file.

Comment: *"I know can use a database for writing log but i want to make it simpler."* - If your approach doesn't work, it's not really "simpler".  Databases handle concurrency for you, as opposed to trying to handle it yourself.  (And concurrency like this **is not** "simple".)  If you're not using an existing logging library/framework, now would be a great time to start.  They make logging "simple".

Comment: Use a logging framework, log4net for example or any other. Somebody else already fixed the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: Thanks, I do not using any library for log.
Run this lines:
string sfile = "path of file";
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(sfile, true);
file.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString(cFormatDateTime), line));
file.Close();
I'll try with log4net as recomended.
Thanks,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried log4net and perfect. Thanks a lot.